# Reset all corrupted indexes of all databases on a RavenDb server by script

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I have a RavenDb server with over 200 databases each with 5 - 10 indexes. Recently, the server went very low on disk space, and most of the indexes become corrupted due to this and need to be reset.

Is it possible to reset all indexes which are corrupted, for all databases on a server?

Or maybe just resetting all indexes on all databases for a server, irrespective if they are corrupt or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least 2 options:

- use client to iterate through all databases and all indexes (and optionally check if index is corrupted) and reset index.
- using REST API:

  1. List databases, ex: GET http://3.live-test.ravendb.net/databases
  2. List indexes for database, ex: GET http://3.live-test.ravendb.net/databases/Northwind/indexes-stats output of this endpoint contains information about index health status
  3. Reset index, ex. RESET http://3.live-test.ravendb.net/databases/Northwind/indexes/Orders/ByCompany

*Note*: Please remember about paging

REST Docs:

- https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/http/client-api/commands/how-to/get-names-of-all-databases-on-a-server
- https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/http/client-api/commands/indexes/how-to/reset-index

Comment: `optionally check if index is corrupted` how? there is no 'IsCorrupted' property on each index. If your suggestion is to use `IsInvalidIndex` then the docs state for this field `Determines if index is invalid. If more thant 15% of attemps (map or reduce) are errors then value will be true` - this isn't directly saying its a corrupted index